# In C++, what can I do to format my output?

Tags: c++, format, output

For example, if my output is: -

```
King of Spades
Queen of Hearts
Four of Diamonds
Nine of Clubs
Three of Diamonds
Deuce of Spades
Ace of Hearts
```

Then what can I do to show it like: -

```
 King of Spades
Queen of Hearts
 Four of Diamonds
 Nine of Clubs
Three of Diamonds
Deuce of Spades
  Ace of Hearts
```

I just need to align the `of's`. Somebody told me `setw` can help.

Is that so? And if it can, then how?

Comment: Maybe you should look up the documentation for `setw`, then give it a think on how you might use it to solve the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Calculate the max length of the first words you want to display then call setw with that.

```
cout << setw(5) << "Four" << " of " << "Hearts" << endl;
cout << setw(5) << "Queen" << " of " << "Diamonds" << endl;
```

Obviously replace the hardcoded strings by your variables.

Answer (score 2):

If you know the maximum field width (5 in this case), then you can indeed use `setw` to pad the first word to that width:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

std::cout << std::setw(5) << card.value << " of " << card.suit << std::endl;
```

There are [other manipulators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip) which might be of interest, such as `setfill` to specify which character to fill the padding with, and `left` and `right` to specify which side of the field to pad.